# Increment number field by 1 on a daily basis

Tags: formula, workflow, custom-field

We're looking to auto increment a number value field on Cases by 1 for every day the case has been open (i.e. auto-increment as long as the case is **not** closed).

What would be the best way to go about this?  A time based workflow action wouldn't get me what I need.  I tried a formula field, but, I'm not sure that it would work without referencing the formula field itself.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would simply use  a formula field to calculate this.  Should be simple enough for calculating Case age regardless of business hours.  An example from the salesforce docs:

https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/useful_advanced_formulas.htm#CaseAgingAllCases

If you need business hours involved, then a more complex formula is needed like in the link below.

https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HYXJEA4

Answer (score 5):

You can create a formula field to do this

IF(IsClosed, 
ROUND(ClosedDate - CreatedDate, 0), ROUND((NOW() - CreatedDate),0))

https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HYXJEA4